# AngularJS Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two functions in my AngularJS Controller file:

```
function1(param1, param2) {
    var relevantObjects  = [];
    // do some work
    return relevantObjects;
}

function2(relevantObjects) {
    var containedTimeRangeObjectArray = [];
    // do some work
    return containedTimeRangeObjectArray;
}
```

The AngularJS Code in HTML looks like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="containedTimeRangeObject in vm.function2(vm.function1(param1, param2))">                                  
    {{containedTimeRangeObject.type}}
    {{containedTimeRangeObject.percentage}}
</span>
```

The problem now is that my model will not become stable because in function2() a new array is generated at every invocation and then function1() is invoced because model has chanced and so on (thats my guess)

My question now would be how to solve this problem? I also use function1() without function 2 like this way:

```
<span ng-repeat="containedTimeRangeObject in vm.function1(param1, param2)">                                
    {{containedTimeRangeObject. ...}}
    {{containedTimeRangeObject. ...}}
</span>
```

and this works fine.
I would be thankful wor any hint how to solve this issue.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it necessary to execute the function every time? If not why you don't use `ng-init="items = function()"` and `ng-repeat="item in items"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately data can change - ng-init is not the solution for me. Is there any other possibility how to solve this issue. thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you can use `$watch`. Like this: `$scope.$watch('param1', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.items = function1(newValue);
});`

Comment: I have reproduced my problem by a simple application: [MyJSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9yyp09zw/1/). Sorry, but I could not separate HTML and JS. Currently I am still a dummy concerning AngularJS, therefore it was not clear for my to follow the $scope.$watch issue - Would it be possible that you can explain this issue in my example. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I added $watch to your example https://jsfiddle.net/9gapurg1/

Comment: Thanks once again Christoph for your help. I have tried to implement the solution but I failed. I have posted the whole of my code under [My code](https://jsfiddle.net/9gapurg1/2/). The two problematic functions are: **getCalendarViewSchedules** and **calculatePercentageOfDateTime**. It would be great if you could give me another hint to solve this soultion. It is not clear for me which parameter I should watch and how I can do it in my application. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87895/discussion-between-user3318489-and-christoph).